# How to use mdl-select and md-option

Tags: angular2-mdl

I've been using angular2-mdl for a while and it's brilliant, now I want to also use @angular2-mdl-ext on a project using systemjs but am having trouble and get errors indicating mdl-select and mdl-option is not known in component. I did an import of MdlSelectModule on the component but it does not help.

How should I specify this in app.module.ts and  and systemjs.config.js, all attempts at getting it to resolve have failed thus far.

I tried import MdlSelectModule in app.module.ts but keep etting a 404  error which tells me systemjs is not configured properly....?

An example indicatig how to specify in systemjs.config.js and app.module.ts would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by setting mapping in systemjs as follows

'@angular2-mdl-ext/select': 'npm:@angular2-mdl-ext/select/index.umd.js',